# Cannot see pyc files in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyc

I am using PyCharm for a project and I need to access *pyc* files.
Unfortunately, IDE seems not to show `*.pyc` files nor `__pycache__`, even in searches with double <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. I cannot find settings or documentation about it. Do you have any idea on how can I show these files and folders in IDE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is **Settings... | Editor | File Types | Ignore Files and Folders**. Remove `*.pyc` and `__pycache__` from the list to see the files.

[image]